# Can implicit conversion be used to satisfy supertype argument?

Tags: c#

I have an interface `PropertyReference`, an implementation `Literal` and an implicit conversion operator from `int` to `Literal`. However, whenever I try to use an `int` where a `PropertyReference` is expected the compiler complains `cannot convert from int to PropertyReference`.

The compiler does not let me add a conversion operator in `PropertyReference` because `Interfaces cannot contain conversion, equality or inequality operators`. I have a `PropertyReferenceExtension` static class and cannot put the conversion operator there because `static classes cannot contain user-defined operators`.

Is there a way to perform an implicit conversion to a subtype to match a supertype or must the conversion be explicit? `PropertyReference` and `Literal` are in the same namespace and the class where the conversion is being tried is already `using FooBarNamespace`

The statement that fails to compile.

```
Assert.IsTrue(BigDouble.Equals(Min.Of(1,2,3), 1));
```

Signature for `Min.Of`

```
public static Min Of(params PropertyReference[] children)
```

Signature for implicit conversion

```
public static implicit operator Literal(int value) => new Literal(new BigDouble(value));
```

Comment: Could you please show us some sample code?

Comment: Consider this: if Bar1 and Bar2 both implement Foo, and both provide an implicit int->Bar1 or int->Bar2 conversion, how would .NET choose which one you want?

Comment: OP, I assume [this](https://rextester.com/MPT47013) demonstrates what you're talking about.

Comment: @John Yes, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#processing-of-user-defined-implicit-conversions. An implicit conversion will only be found by the compiler if it exists in either the source type, or destination type, or one of their base types.

Since you are trying to convert from an `int` to a `PropertyReference`, only those types can implement the implicit conversion. But `PropertyReference` is an interface, which is explicitly not allowed. Though this does seem like a rather arbitrary restriction.

If you were to convert `PropertyReference` to an abstract base class, you could define an implicit operator that converts an `int` to a `PropertyReference` by creating a `Literal`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an overload like below?

```
public static Min Of(params PropertyReference[] children)
{

}

public static Min Of(params Literal[] children)
{
    return Of((PropertyReference[]) children);
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work as being able to mix various kinds of PropertyReference is the point of using an interface.